# UpdateAttribute and PutFile - filename gets a single-quote?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am working through a Nifi process group that generates a flowfile. I am trying to update the `filename` attribute, but I notice a single quote gets added to the file too.

[image: UpdateAttribute]

In there, you see `#{snmp.hostname}-${now()}.json`

This does work, but when I look at the output I see:

[image: ls of output]

I don't see the quotes when I keep the flowfile filename as is. Here is my PutFile settings, pretty much the default:

[image: PutFile Settings]

Here is what is looks like when I don't update attribute, you see the file: `6fd0fcec-c838-4938-a600-5dbe99c4a370` (I do notice a leading space in that flowfile name too?).

[image]

Running NiFi 1.16.0 on a RHEL 8.5 machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the problem. The problem was the date format in `now()` contained spaces. It seems NiFi will inject a quote around the file name if there are spaces. Replacing `${now()}` with `${now():format("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "America/Los_Angeles")}` gets rid of the spaces and leads to:

[image: Screen shot of it working]

And that solves the problem.